# Renaming app in Android Market during upgrade

Tags: android, upgrade, rename, google-play

I want to rename my published app during next upgrade, will the Android Market treat this as just another regular upgrade and preserve the associated ratings and comments?  The app will keep the same package name.

Comment: chee did you ever get an answer to this? Does anybody have an answer to this?

Answer (score 6):

As long as the package name is same , it doesn't matter what app name you keep. I frequently switch my apps Title(in market) and also app_name . and everything remains the same

Comment: Can it cause installation problems when renaming? E.g. some users reported problems while upgrading when they have a short cut to the app

Comment: So far i have never faced any such problems. Some users do complain about difficulty to find the app in the market , which is perfectly understandable