# Are there any implications of renaming a published android application?

Tags: android, rename, google-play

I'm about to change the application name of a fairly popular Android app published on Google Play.

I know how to do it, but I would also like to be sure that nothing but the name will be changed. For example I don't want to loose the application's position in the search results.

Is there anyone that has renamed a published application and can confirm that nothing but the name will change?

Best regards,
Andreas

EDIT: With "application name" I'm refering to the application label that you set in the manifest file, not the package name or the name of the apk.

Comment: Do you mean the apk name ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the app name really has nothing to do with the listing or the position for that matter. That is all managed by the package name. As long as you don't change that, your app will hold whatever position it occupies on the store. And yes. I have changed the app name a couple of times (changed it once and then again to fix a typo) ;-)

Comment: Thank you Siddharth Lele! Your comment is an accepted answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220492/renaming-app-in-android-market-during-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

If you mention that the app has changed name within the description i.e. "App1 is now App2!"

It should still show up in search when people search the old name, for 'rankings' it's based on the package name and should keep it's position.